# "configuring network interfaces", prompting for password

Tags: networking, wireless

It happens a few times each day. WiFi stops working, disconnects, asks for password and doesn't accept the correct one. It can't also connect to open WiFi even though it can see it.

The only thing that works is physically removing network card from USB and putting it back again.

How to diagnose and correct this problem?

My system is kubuntu 16.04.

Result of lsusb, when WiFi dies (Atheros is the device):

```
   Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1058:0748 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport (WDBKXH, WDBY8L)
   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
   Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
   Bus 002 Device 033: ID 0cf3:1006 Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN322G v3 / TL-WN422G v2 802.11g [Atheros AR9271]
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04f9:0027 Brother Industries, Ltd HL-2030 Laser Printer
   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
   Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 008 Device 012: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
   Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Result of dmesg (ath9k and wlan0 are culprits):

```
    [749216.052827] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
    [749216.063545] Broke affinity for irq 17
    [749216.063551] Broke affinity for irq 19
    [749216.063567] Broke affinity for irq 24
    [749216.063570] Broke affinity for irq 26
    [749216.064605] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
    [749216.078758] Broke affinity for irq 1
    [749216.078765] Broke affinity for irq 9
    [749216.078768] Broke affinity for irq 12
    [749216.078771] Broke affinity for irq 14
    [749216.078777] Broke affinity for irq 17
    [749216.078780] Broke affinity for irq 18
    [749216.078783] Broke affinity for irq 19
    [749216.078799] Broke affinity for irq 24
    [749216.078803] Broke affinity for irq 26
    [749216.079841] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
    [749216.091770] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
    [749216.091796] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
    [749216.091813] PCI-DMA: Resuming GART IOMMU
    [749216.091813] PCI-DMA: Restoring GART aperture settings
    [749216.091819] LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
    [749216.098039] microcode: CPU0: new patch_level=0x0600084f
    [749216.098091] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
    [749216.115914] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
    [749216.115915] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
    [749216.118885]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
    [749216.119052] CPU1 is up
    [749216.140000] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
    [749216.142882]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
    [749216.148271] microcode: CPU2: new patch_level=0x0600084f
    [749216.148312] CPU2 is up
    [749216.168015] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
    [749216.170934]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
    [749216.171106] CPU3 is up
    [749216.188062] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x4
    [749216.190998]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
    [749216.196399] microcode: CPU4: new patch_level=0x0600084f
    [749216.196443] CPU4 is up
    [749216.216089] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x5
    [749216.219055]  cache: parent cpu5 should not be sleeping
    [749216.219225] CPU5 is up
    [749216.226852] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
    [749216.227251] ahci 0000:00:11.0: set SATA to AHCI mode
    [749216.227288] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.227307] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.227403] ohci-pci 0000:00:14.5: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.227443] ohci-pci 0000:00:16.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.239896] ehci-pci 0000:00:16.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.239899] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.240005] pcieport 0000:00:04.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.240025] ehci-pci 0000:00:13.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.240132] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 13.040 msecs
    [749216.240638] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.491 msecs
    [749216.240763] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.240875] usb usb8: root hub lost power or was reset
    [749216.240876] usb usb9: root hub lost power or was reset
    [749216.240878] pcieport 0000:00:09.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
    [749216.250500] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 1002:5a16 = 31cd02/0
    [749216.250502] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
    [749216.254068] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x00000000002E8000).
    [749216.254165] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
    [749216.254166] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800cf728c00
    [749216.254168] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800cf728c04
    [749216.254169] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800cf728c08
    [749216.254170] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800cf728c0c
    [749216.254171] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800cf728c10
    [749216.254656] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000075a18 and cpu addr 0xffffc90001835a18
    [749216.259852] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
    [749216.259878] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
    [749216.274626] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 6 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c18 and cpu addr 0xffff8800cf728c18
    [749216.274627] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 7 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c1c and cpu addr 0xffff8800cf728c1c
    [749216.428086] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:08:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
    [749216.428088] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/03:22:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
    [749216.444189] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
    [749216.575869] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
    [749216.575913] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
    [749216.723940] usb 8-2: reset low-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
    [749216.777154] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
    [749216.777157] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
    [749216.777161] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
    [749216.777173] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 9 usecs
    [749216.777178] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 3 usecs
    [749216.778667] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth7: link down
    [749216.832445] usb 2-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
      [749216.952880] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
    [749216.952897] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
    [749217.020479] usb 8-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
    [749217.020483] usb 8-2: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
    [749217.062064] [drm] ring test on 6 succeeded in 12 usecs
    [749217.062076] [drm] ring test on 7 succeeded in 4 usecs
    [749217.062077] [drm] VCE initialized successfully.
    [749217.062105] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
    [749217.062128] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
    [749217.062151] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
    [749217.062180] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
    [749217.062204] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
    [749217.083382] ath9k_htc 2-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
    [749217.712061] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
    [749218.212115] [drm] ib test on ring 6 succeeded
    [749218.712162] [drm] ib test on ring 7 succeeded
    [749218.963725] PM: resume of devices complete after 2722.782 msecs
    [749218.964440] PM: Finishing wakeup.
    [749218.964442] Restarting tasks ... done.
    [749220.556312] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
    [749220.562827] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
    [749223.708652] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
    [749223.708729] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    [749223.746993] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s6: link is not ready
    [749223.748788] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth7: link is not ready
    [749223.870717] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth7: link down
    [749223.870826] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth7: link is not ready
    [749223.872789] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    [749224.032812] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    [749224.077325] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    [749225.168521] wlan0: authenticate with e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04
    [749225.316786] wlan0: send auth to e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04 (try 1/3)
    [749225.318975] wlan0: authenticated
    [749225.320845] wlan0: associate with e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04 (try 1/3)
    [749225.324848] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
    [749225.332465] wlan0: associated
    [749225.332523] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
    [749453.178896] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    [749453.178905] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
    [749501.562825] wlan0: deauthenticating from e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    [749501.641285] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
    [749501.641287] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
    [749501.641289] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
    [749501.641293] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749501.641296] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749501.641298] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749501.641300] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749501.641302] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
    [749501.641304] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
    [749501.641306] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749501.641308] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
    [749502.735100] wlan0: authenticate with e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04
    [749502.904046] wlan0: send auth to e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04 (try 1/3)
    [749502.906145] wlan0: authenticated
    [749502.910125] wlan0: associate with e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04 (try 1/3)
    [749502.914198] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
    [749502.920385] wlan0: associated
    [749512.922459] wlan0: deauthenticating from e8:94:f6:ca:dd:04 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    [749512.996216] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
    [749512.996220] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
    [749512.996221] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
    [749512.996224] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749512.996226] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749512.996227] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749512.996229] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749512.996231] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
    [749512.996233] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
    [749512.996235] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
    [749512.996236] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
```

Comment: Could you check if  `dmesg` shows any errors related to the network card?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I wanted to do ping to find moment at which connection breaks, but funnily, when I keep pinging all the time the problem disappears.